# Permission InboundMigrationToolsUser depends on permission(s): ModifyAllData

Tags: deployment, permissions, profile, change-set

I am getting the following error when I am trying to deploy components using `change sets`. I am not sure what `InboundMigrationToolsUser` permission even refers to. All the permissions for the affected profiles are the same in both Sandbox and Production.

The error I am getting while trying to deploy is `Permission InboundMigrationToolsUser depends on permission(s): ModifyAllData`

Comment: can you please copy your deployment error message?

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. There have been changes made to `Deploy Change Set` permission. Profiles having `Deploy Change Set` set as true should also have `Modify All Data` as true. `InboundMigrationToolsUser` refers to `Deploy Change Set` permission.